# recreate xdg directories after accidentally deleting it

Tags: linux, configuration, file-manager, xdg

im running xdg-user-dirs-update command, which create two files in .config directory, user-dirs.dirs and user-dirs.locale. user-dirs.dirs lookes like this:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"
```

why its empty even after changing XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/" to XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop" directories still not creating why?
how can i get my full home dirs back?

Answer (score 4):

`xdg-user-dirs-update` is part of the answer, but its default behavior is to reassign missing directories to `$HOME`, not recreate them.

To recreate the directories, do this:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --force
```

Depending on your desktop environment, You may have to logout/login to get the emblems in your file manager.

Comment: That's the answer, it even adresses [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347087/recreate-xdg-directories-after-accidentally-deleting-it#comment614190_347095).

Comment: @FelipeS.S.Schneider thank you for your appreciation of my answer. The standard practice in this case is to upvote the answer (in practice, by clicking on the triangle upwards next to the beginning of the answer).

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the Folder.

Example `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"` In `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults` You can show the names of the standart folder. Correct your File and run `xdg-user-dirs-update` again. The right locale for you will be set automatical.

Comment: that's the problem even after i add folder names like $HOME/Dowloads, and when i run xdg-user-dirs-update i'm getting the message: /home/void/Desktop was removed, reassigning DESKTOP to homedir

Comment: which distrie ?  `env | grep -i xdg`